# Set &raquo; HTML entity in JavaScript's document.title?

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

I'm setting `document.title` with JavaScript, and I can't find a way to supply » (`&raquo`) without it appearing as literal text.

Here's my code:

```
document.title = 'Home &raquo; site.com';
```

If I use &raquo ; in the title tag of the document it works great and displays correctly as », but it seems to be unescaping when I include it in `document.title`.

Any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: try 'Home ' + &raquo; + ' site.com';

Comment: @DOK that just will not work. Such markup only works when an XML or HTML parser is involved, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try

```
document.title = 'Home \u00bb site.com';
```

Generally you can look up your special character at a [site like this](http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html/extras/entities.html) and then, once you know the numeric code, you can construct a Unicode escape sequence in your JavaScript string.  Here, that character is code 187, which is "bb" in hex.  JavaScript Unicode escapes look like "\u" followed by 4 hex digits.

Comment: Ugh. Yes, it works, but as a developer, when I encounter this code, I'm gonna be stumped. Even if I know this syntax, I'll have to go look u00bb up. SLaks' solution is so much easier to read.

Comment: @DOK well that's true, but on the other hand this way will work no matter what character set your sources are maintained as.  It's more reliable in that respect. (Also, if you're a developer, I would hope you'd be resourceful enough to figure out what the character is :-)

Answer (score 10):

Javascript does not use HTML entities.

You should simply use the actual `»` character in your string, and make sure that the file is saved and sent as UTF8.

Answer (score 10):

`document.title` takes the string as it is, so you can do this:

```
document.title = 'Home » site.com';
```

If you need to provide it as the entity name, you can set the innerHTML attribute. Here are two examples of how you can do it.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = '&raquo;';
// or
document.querySelector('title').innerHTML = "&raquo;";
```

Comment: I don't have any choice about my data, so this is solves my problem!

Comment: Right idea, but wrong implementation. This will fail in (at least) early versions of Android (I was trying to do the same thing) with a DOM Exception.

The correct implementation is to create a temporary element, fill it's innerHTML, then pull the text content and use that for your document.title set.

A good function can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1912522/1555726

Comment: For jQuery just do `$('title').html('&raquo;');`