# How to update an html element with ascii charaters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to append the ascii character `&#9888;` to some element's title attribute.

When I used `"jQuery(this)[0].title = title;"` I get the raw values.  I've also tried `.attr('title', value)`  Any idea how to update the title attribute with ascii?

Example
[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/8ze2q0ze/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set &raquo; HTML entity in JavaScript's document.title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202470/set-raquo-html-entity-in-javascripts-document-title)

Comment: Did the .text() solution I provided work out? If so, could you please slect my answer as a correct solution? Thanks

Comment: @SterlingBeason  Nope,  adding .text() to a string doesn't work.

Comment: @NullReference I updated my answer with a working jsfiddle. The ascii character was not the issue. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** After looking at your jsfiddle, I realized what you were encountering and how to fix it. Your selector was incorrect and html() was needed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("label").each(function(index){  
   var title = jQuery(this).attr('title');
                    title += '&#10; &#9888; Stats are incomplete due to the video being recently published'
                    jQuery(this).html(title);
  });
});
```

**UPDATED JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/8ze2q0ze/1/

<s>This question has been answered here: [HTML Entity Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode)</s>

<s>Add the **.text()** to your variable. Like this:</s>

<s>jQuery(this)[0].title = title.text();</s>